# How to access variable of a function in another function inside a class?

Tags: oop

I am new to OOP and need some clarification of some concepts. I have a simple class with a private variable and two simple functions. Function one sets the value of the private variable to 40. Now how can I access the value of variable inside function two so the variable value is 40?

```
class MyClass { 

    //declaring private variable:
    private $var = '';

    function MyfuncOne(){
        $this->var = "40";
    }

    function MyfuncTwo(){
    }
}
```

How do I get access to the value of `$this->var` which is 40 that is declared in MyfuncOne()?

Answer (score 2):

In function two you can access it like:

```
function MyFuncTwo() {
    print $this -> var; // Just access it, its a member variable of the same class
}
```

The variable is private to other classes that inherit from this class (can't be accessed), but is entirely accessible from other member functions.

***Edit on Default Constructors***
If you want to set the value to 40 without calling the function first, you'll likely need a default constructor.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Simply:

```
class MyClass {     
    //declaring private variable:
    private $var = '';

    // This is the default constructor, it gets called when you create the object
    function __construct() {
        $this -> var = "40";
    }

    function MyfuncOne(){
        $this->var = "40";
    }

    function MyfuncTwo(){
    }

    function get_var() {
        return $this -> var;
    }
}
```

Then when you make your object, it will be set to "40":

```
$obj = new MyClass();
print "The object's var is " . $obj -> get_var(); // Notice we didn't have to call MyFuncOne(), it's just set.
```

Comment: thankyou but if I simply access it by $this->var in function two, I wont get $this->var = 40

Comment: If you call function one first, you will. You are likely looking for a default constructor (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) that sets the value when the object is first created.

Comment: Thankyou for your help but is there a way that I can get $this->var value to 40 without calling the function one first?